# how do I label the nodes in a network graph? by importing networkx in python?

Tags: python, random, matplotlib

This is my code, I am plotting a randomly generated graph containing 8 nodes

```
import networkx as nx  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import random  
from sets import Set  
from array import array  

def draw_graph(graph):  

# extract nodes from graph
    nodes = set([n1 for n1, n2 in graph] + [n2 for n1, n2 in graph])

# create networkx graph
    G=nx.Graph()

# add nodes
    for node in nodes:
        G.add_node(node)

# add edges
    for edge in graph:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

# draw graph
    pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos)

# show graph
    plt.show()  


##draw example
zero=random.choice([1,4])  
one=random.choice([2,3])  
two=random.choice([1,7])  
three=random.choice([1,5])  
four=random.choice([0,6])  
five=random.choice([3,7])  
seven=random.choice([2,5])  

graph = [(0,zero),(1,one),(2,two),(3,three),(4,four),(5,five),(6,4),(7,seven)]  
draw_graph(graph)
```

now I have to label each node and I has to know positions of each node.. How to do it?? thanks in advance..

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: See the networkx examples.  e.g. https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples/drawing/labels_and_colors.html